# Rails. Debugging a Uniqueness validation with scope that fails when object is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, controller

I have a model `Prediction` for which its instances have references to other models `Participant` and `Match` through the  attributes `:participant_id` `:match_id`.

The idea is that a @participant can have only one @prediction per @match (every @participant is allowed to give maximum one prediction per  @match).

So I've included the following validation in my Prediction model

```
validates :match_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:participant_id] }
```

The validation works OK to disallow @prediction objects to be created when there's already a @prediciton for the same @match and @participant. The problem is that it does, as well, prevent updating an object even though I'm not changing those assigned ids of the original object. Plus, it's letting me update only one instance of Prediction, all other's through an error.

What's puzzling is that it was working fine but for some reason, I've been unable to track, it stopped working and I have run out of ideas on how to debug. Could you provide any ideas? Below what I've checked/tried:

The relevant params of a failed request:

```
"prediction"=><ActionController::Parameters {"participant_id"=>"1", "match_id"=>"2", "local_score"=>"2", "visitant_score"=>"0"}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
 @details={:match_id=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>2}]},
 @messages={:match_id=>["has already been taken"]}>
```

There are plenty predictions in the database with `match_id: 2`. However, this is happening despite having no other @prediction in the database with both `match_id: 2` and `participant_id: 1` except, of course, for the instance that throws this error while updating.

Funnily enough, if I try the same operation in the console (as below) it successfully updates.

```
@prediction = Prediction.find_by(participant_id: 1, match_id: 2)
@prediction.update_attributes(local_score: 8, visitant_score: 8)
```

Suggesting the problem is in the controller action:

*app/controllers/predicitons_controller.rb*

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @prediction.update(prediction_params)
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @prediction }
        format.js
      else
        @errorMessages = []
        @prediction.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            @errorMessages << message
        end
        format.js {render template: 'predictions/update_error'}
      end
    end
  end
```

I see no problem there. Additionally, it seems that the only request sent to the controller that updates successfully is:

```
 "prediction"=><ActionController::Parameters {"participant_id"=>"1", "match_id"=>"1", "local_score"=>"1", "visitant_score"=>"1"}
```

And if I do these others, for example, it doesn't:

```
"prediction"=><ActionController::Parameters {"participant_id"=>"2", "match_id"=>"1", "local_score"=>"0", "visitant_score"=>"0"}

"prediction"=><ActionController::Parameters {"participant_id"=>"2", "match_id"=>"2", "local_score"=>"9", "visitant_score"=>"9"}

"prediction"=><ActionController::Parameters {"participant_id"=>"4", "match_id"=>"1", "local_score"=>"1", "visitant_score"=>"1"
```

All of these failed requests throw the "match_id already taken" error and  update just fine in the console.

The controller request is touching the correct action with the method: :put. I've tried to change the syntax of the validation switching   match_id for pool_id (which of course shouldn't make a difference) with no success.

Any, help would be appreciated.

---

app/models/prediction.rb

```
class MatchPrediction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant
  belongs_to :match
  validates :match_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:pool_participant_id] }
  def correct_score?
    if match.official_outcome
      local_score == match.local_score && visitant_score == match.visitant_score ? true : false
    end
  end
  def correct_outcome?
    if match.official_outcome
      predicted_outcome == match.official_outcome ? true : false
    end
  end
end
```

and server output pre rollback:

```
Started PUT "/pools/1/predictions/19" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-29 18:17:11 +1100
Processing by PredictionsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SagJX+a7m0eCAdH7AdA0eYz6BVL1cesXYXOUkoe2FRynta6wyiWdskrC1007V1vyrIApPtdEQnVHWlzhSeJs5Q==", "prediction"=>{"participant_id"=>"4", "match_id"=>"2", "local_score"=>"7", "visitant_score"=>"0"}, "pool_id"=>"1", "id"=>"19"}
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@global/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15
  Prediction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "predictions".* FROM "predictions" WHERE "predictions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:86
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:55
  Participant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:55
  Match Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE "matches"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:55
  Prediction Exists (1.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "predictions" WHERE "predictions"."match_id" = $1 AND "predictions"."id" != $2 AND "predictions"."participant_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["match_id", 2], ["id", 1], ["participant_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:55
  Pool Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pools".* FROM "pools" WHERE "pools"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/prediction.rb:35
  Round Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "rounds".* FROM "rounds" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "rounds"."id" = "groups"."round_id" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/prediction.rb:21
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/predictions_controller.rb:55
```

Comment: Let's see the Prediction model, and also take a look at your server console output for the queries where it's checking the uniqueness validation.

Comment: In your find by you search by match_id and participant_id . In your controller how do you find the record? by id?

Comment: Guys thanks for your help.
@GorillaApe I think I found the error with your guidance. I missed the essential part and forgot to check how I was setting `@prediction` in the controller. I can't believe I missed this. Due to a recent change in my routes my controller is setting always the same instance (the one that I can update without failure).
I'll revise it and I'm confident I'll be able to solve it.

Comment: ok add more info if you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing mistake really. I missed checking how the Predictions Controller was setting @prediction. I had entred the params to find the object incorrectly as @GorillaApe suggested:

```
def set_match_prediction
  @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:pool_id])
end
```

instead of:

```
def set_match_prediction
  @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:id])
end
```

this in turn was always setting the same object thus raising the validation error in all but one of the instances which, by chance, its :id coincided with :pool_id.